# ISO8583 Simulator with user Interface

Tags: iso8583

I want to work on ISO 8583 model for ATM/POS transactions. Are there any open simulators available to test and process the ISO8583 to bitmap/ASCII along a user interface ??

Python langauge is prefereable but anything else is ok.

Answer (score 5):

The primary ISO8583 Simulators on the Market today and I have used all three.

- [ACI's ASSET](http://www.aciworldwide.com/products-and-services/payments-infrastructure/payment-testing/asset.aspx)
- FIS / Clear-To-Pay [Open Test Solutions](http://www.fisglobal.com/products-opentestsolutions) (Formerly Lexcel)
- [Paragon FasTest](http://www.paragonedge.com/products/fastest-for-iso.html)

All are commercial products that are purchased separate of the Payment application and well worth the investment. You can purchase the basic software application and then build the configuration specific to your interface you are testing with at least the ACI & Paragon one pretty easily using their scripting and database configurations. They also offer several pre-built ones that include mandates support for purchase as well.

Many payment applications come with a very basic simulator of sorts as well, just as [Postilion](http://www.aciworldwide.com/products-and-services/retail-payments/payments-processing/postilion-for-banks-and-processors.aspx) comes with SinkSim and SourceSim..and I believe [BPC Payments](http://www.bpcbt.com/)'s solution also comes with one but they are very limited.

JPOS apparently has some sort of simulator [based on this Blog Post](http://jpos.org/blog/2013/07/setting-up-the-client-simulator/), but I have not used it. There is apparently a base one and [one that runs in Eclipse](https://github.com/jpos/jPOS-EE/blob/master/doc/src/asciidoc/module_client_simulator.adoc).

I have seen some other smaller scale ones out there that are not as robust or as easier to use as the commercial ones. Searching GitHub for ISO8583 and Simulator you find several hits but do not believe any have a UI like you are requesting.

I have not seen one to date that has Python integration, but also have not proactively looked specifically for that feature as all commercial ones support automation, export, reporting, etc and many basic things you would expect of a commercial payments simulator.